# Accept integer numbers as input, one at a time, in a single field

Tags: c#

Quick note - I am very new to c# so I apologize if this is stupid simple.

I am having a hard time trying to complete a simple c# task in a book.

My Task -
Create a Windows application accepting integer numbers as input, one at a time, in a single 
field. A button should cause displaying that number right below the input field, but only 
if it is larger than the currently displayed number (or it’s the first number processed). As soon as 
zero (0) has been processed, stop accepting more input and display (above the input field) the 
sum of all the entered numbers.

Here's what I have so far -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
            listofNumbers = new List<int>();
        }

        List<int> listofNumbers;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //convert input to integer
            int orginalInput = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            //add numbers to list
            listofNumbers.Add(orginalInput);

            string txt = "";

            foreach (int originalNumber in listofNumbers)
            {
                //find numbers greater than previously entered number
                int higherNumber = listofNumbers.Find(item => item > originalNumber);

                if (listofNumbers.Count == 1 || originalNumber < higherNumber)
                {
                    txt += higherNumber + " ";
                    label1.Text = txt;
                }


            }

            textBox1.Clear();


        }
    }
}
```

I haven't started to add the inputs ( As soon as zero (0) has been processed, stop accepting more input and display (above the input field) the sum of all the entered numbers.)

I'm still trying to figure out the first part of the task.

Problems that I have - 
--The first number displayed is a zero even though I type a different number.
--It seems to spit out random numbers if I type in a lower number than what was previously typed.

Any help or pointers a greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a suggestion( don't know if it works in your case), but you might want to check the number that was entered before adding to the list.

Comment: If you only need to compare the current number to the last number, why are you adding all the numbers to a `List`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!listofNumbers.Contains(0)){ // check for already zero entered or not
    int input = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    listofNumbers.Add(input); 
    if(input==0){  // if zero entered calculate the sum and set it as label text
       int sum = listofNumbers.Sum();
       label1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }else // otherwise campare with last label value and entered number and set the label
    {
     int maxNo = int.Parse(label1.Text);
     if(input>maxNo)
     {
        label1.Text = input.ToString();
     }
    }
}
```